# How to download and use offline maps in Map API V2?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I build app with maps and i'm saving markers position and etc. to prefferences
I need to restart app without internet connection and map will be work.
How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps aren't designed for offline browsing. You would need to get in Maps app installed on your device, and then save map fragment in order to work offline.
Instruction how to do it is here https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/3273567?hl=en